# Regular closed subset of H-closed space

Tags: general-topology

An H-closed space $X$ is a topological space which is closed in any Hausdorff space in which it is embedded. A well-known characterization is that $X$ is H-closed iff every open cover of $X$  has a finite proximate subcover, i.e. a finite subcollection whose union is dense.

I need to show that this property is hereditary to regular closed subsets. I tried to do something analogous to the proof of closed subset of Compact spaces are compact. But got stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is an error. The subcollection should have dense union, not closure.

Comment: @Victor Gustavo May: thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be H-closed, and let $F$ be a regular closed set in $X$. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a relatively open cover of $F$. For each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ there is an open $V_U$ in $X$ such that $U=F\cap V_U$; let

$$\mathscr{V}=\{X\setminus F\}\cup\{V_U:U\in\mathscr{U}\}\;.$$

$\mathscr{V}$ is an open cover of $X$, so it has a finite proximate subcover $\mathscr{V}_0$. Let

$$\mathscr{U}_0=\{U\in\mathscr{U}:V_U\in\mathscr{V}_0\}\;;$$

clearly $\mathscr{U}_0$ is a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$. Since $\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus F)\cap\operatorname{int}F=\varnothing$, and $\bigcup\mathscr{V}_0$ is dense in $X$, $\bigcup\{V_U:U\in\mathscr{U}_0\}$ must be dense in $\operatorname{int}F$, and hence $\bigcup\mathscr{U}_0$ must be dense in $\operatorname{int}F$. Thus,

$$F=\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}F\subseteq\bigcup_{U\in\mathscr{U}_0}\operatorname{cl}U\subseteq F\;,$$

$\mathscr{U}_0$ is a proximate subcover of $\mathscr{U}$, and $F$ is H-closed.

It is also true that a space $X$ is H-closed iff every open filter in $X$ has a cluster point, and we can use this characterization instead. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a relatively open filter on $F$, and let $\mathscr{B}=\{U\cap\operatorname{int}F:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$. Clearly $U\cap\operatorname{int}F\ne\varnothing$ for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$, so $\mathscr{B}$ is an open filterbase in $X$. $X$ is H-closed, so the filter $\mathscr{V}$ generated by $\mathscr{B}$ has a cluster point $x\in X$, which is evidently also a cluster point of $\mathscr{U}$. And $\operatorname{int}F\in\mathscr{V}$, so every nbhd of $x$ meets $\operatorname{int}F$, and therefore $x\in\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}F=F$, so that $\mathscr{U}$ has a cluster point in $F$.

Comment: Is the filter used in the second criterion with respect to inclusion?

Comment: @Jerrytheundergrad: Yes, just an ordinary filter of open sets.

Comment: @Jerrytheundergrad Yes, a filter in the lattice of all open sets (operations union and intersection). So a collection of open sets that does not contain $\emptyset$, is closed under finite intersections and any open set that is a superset of a member is in it as well.